# onBindViewHolder is only called for the first element I have clicked in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have fragment in which there is recyclerview and setting adapter to it. If I click the first add to cart and then second. After that when fragment is restarted only first add to cart status is changed. And similarly If i click first the second add to cart element in recyclerview after restart only second add to cart status is getting changed. I want to call the onBindViewHolder position from 0 to last element in adapter. In ViewHolder class there is Add_to_cart change listener.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MilkAdapter1.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // I need to call this method for all elements in recyclerview whenever restarted 
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                if (name.equals(holder.product_name.getText().toString())) {  // if present just update the AddToCart status
                   // if add_to_cart element is present in sqlite Database, just update its status
                    holder.textView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // this will change the Add to Cart status
                    holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.digit.setText(quantit + "");
                }
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
        c.close();
    }

}
```

Sorry, I can't upload image to my app because of less reputations.

Comment: Your `name` variable only matches with one of your list items, so only one is updated. If you want to update multiple items at once, you must store the selected items in an array or collection to be able to store several ones. Anyway, it is kind of difficult to help you solve it just with the onBindViewHolder method. Could you show what do you do in the onClick method of the list items?

Comment: whenever addtocart button is clicked it saves the values in cart table if not exists. addtocart button hides and [- quantity +] this kind of layout gets visible.

Comment: this method is called for only one item in the list which add to cart button i have clicked first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are storing your selected items in an ArrayList (which I encourage you to do if you aren't), the solution would be:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MilkAdapter1.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // I need to call this method for all elements in recyclerview whenever restarted 
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            if (nameArrayList.contains(holder.product_name.getText().toString())) {  // if present just update the AddToCart status
                   // if add_to_cart element is present in sqlite Database just update its status
                holder.textView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // this will change the Add to Cart status
                holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.digit.setText(quantit + "");
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
        c.close();
    }
}
```

As Sachin Soma pointed, you don't need a `for` loop, since `onBindViewHolder` will be invoked once for every item in your list.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using position don't use for loop..

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }


public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MilkAdapter1.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // I need to call this method for all elements in recyclerview whenever restarted 
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

                if (name.equals(holder.product_name.getText().toString())) {  // if present just update the AddToCart status
                   // if add_to_cart element is present in sqlite Database just update its status
                    holder.textView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // this will change the Add to Cart status
                    holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.digit.setText(quantit + "");

            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
        c.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: without for loop its called only once for the first Add to Cart I have clicked.

Comment: you have to return list.size() inside getItemCount() method.

Comment: I have returned list.size()

Comment: Its because your list is having only one element.please check it.

Comment: list.size() returning 3 bcz it has 3 objects.